# setsebool and run scripts in home directory

Tags: selinux

I configured SELinux:

```
semanage login -a -s user_u mary
setsebool user_exec_content off
```

The general configuration is

```
SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

When I login to the mary account I can still run the scripts in her account but setsebool ( user_exec_content=off) should forbid do it?

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: When the user is logged in, do you see them as confined in `ps -feZ`?  Do they log in via ssh; and if so, is `UsePAM` set to yes in sshd_config?

Comment: I login throw ssh and login to mary account from root account, but if login to mary account directly from ssh then everything works as it should. I'm done a foolish think.

Comment: To pick up the selinux contexts using `su`, you would need `su - username` and you should see it.  You might try `su - mary -c "id -Z"`

Comment: <pre> su - mary -c "id -Z" </pre> - No it will not only work if you go directly from mary account, if you do through the <pre>su - mary</pre>out of the root, it does not work

Comment: [root@outsider1 ~]# su - mary         [mary@outsider1 ~]$ id -Z       unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

Answer (score 2):

**Selinux user not confined when using su**

Some applications or helpers utilize PAM to get/set SELinux restrictions.  SSHD for example would require that you have `UsePAM yes` for SELinux user restrictions to be enabled.  Depending on your SELinux policies and booleans, you may be able to bypass confinement when using some helpers such as `su` or `sudo` and also depending on how they are executed.  This requires understanding what transitions are allowed in the SELinux policy.

If Mary logs in via SSH and `UsePAM yes` is set, then they should be confined as expected and your boolean should take effect.